# R Bar plot x axis plotting help, x axis not matching data

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a bar plot in R plotting probability distributions on the following data

example data:

```
 mc2
[1] 0.03846154 0.09615385 0.19230769 0.18269231 0.28846154 0.20192308 
> mc2dl
[1] 143 144 145 146 147 148 ### used as x axis labels
```

when I try to plot this the x axis appears vertically

```
barplot.default(mc2, xlab = mc2dl)
```

[image: Example plot]

And when plotting my own axis its length does not = the size of the graph

```
axis(1, 1:6, labels=mc2dl)
```

[image: example plot 2]

p.s I have tried ggplot but it brings its own problems, regarding multiple plots side by side and is in a different format than the rest of my paper.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The barplot object itself contains information about the position of its own bars, so you can do:

```r
my_barplot <- barplot(mc2)
axis(1, at = my_barplot, labels = 143:148)
```

[image]